# How do thumbnail image with a CI Image_nation library?

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I use a new image library in Codeignite for make thumbnails.
So, following [example](http://avenir.ro/image_nation-codeigniter-library/) I tried to make thumbnail of uploaded image:

```
    $ci =& get_instance();
    $ci->load->library('image_nation');

    $conf = array(
        '145x145' => array(
            'master_dim' => 'auto',
            'keep_aspect_ratio' => FALSE,
            'style' => array('vertical'=>'center','horizontal'=>'center'),
            'overwrite' => TRUE,
            'size_folders' => TRUE,
            'quality' => '100%',
            'directory' => $path,
            'file_name' => '_145x145'
        )
    );

    $ci->image_nation->add_size($conf);
    $ci->image_nation->process();
```

Here I specified `$path` is full path to laoded image that I need make thumb.
But thumbnail is not created in folder with a native image.
What do I wrong?

Comment: This is stated at the end of article you linked:
_If you encounter any problems, please do let me know (either with a comment below or with a report issue on github)._ Check with author about CI version and anything else related to library.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't add a source for your thumbnail (the image from which you want to create the thumbnail):

```
$this->image_nation->source('source-image-01.jpg');
```

Also $path shouldn't be the full path to your image, but the directory where you want the image to be saved.